# What could this number represent in an API parameter?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm scraping a website for work, and have come across a parameter I cannot figure out.

Below is the payload supplied to the API call, formatting is for Python Requests module.

Each time I refresh the page, I notice the callback parameter changes:

```
params = (
    ('format', 'json'),
    ('obit_id', '332619'),
    ('limit', '99'),
    ('types', '3'),
    ('page', '2'),
    ('status', 'public'),
    ('public_obit_bypass', '1'),
    ('callback', 'jQuery360033994225984056503_1644719873380'),
    ('_', '1644719873382'),
)
```

I understand the `'_', '1644719873382'` param (also the `_1644719873380` in the callback param) is referring to a unix timestamp.

I suspect that the `jQuery3600` prefixed number is also something meaningful, but can't figure it out. Just curious if anyone else has seen anything similar, or have any resources to look into.

I've done all the normal stuff, Google, looking here, trying to cut the `3600` off the number and plug it into an online converter (still over the 32bit limit though).

EDIT
@Barmar - I solved this with your help. I found the callback was wrapping the JSON response in `jQuery3600[...]_[...] ();` which was nicely dropped by actually omitting the entire `'callback'` param altogether. Thank you!

Comment: It's a cache buster.

Comment: The value is the current time, so it will be different every call.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I'm usually able to replicate this by supplying a Unix converted value to the `params` when sending a request. But I need to figure out how to replicate that `3600[...]` number

Comment: Ok, @Barmar thank you for the insight... I wrote a function to generate a random 17 digit number, prepended that with `jQuery3600` and added the `_{unix_timestamp}` and the API call returns data as expected... Not sure why I thought it needed to be something meaningful.

Comment: It's just a random number followed by a timestamp.

Comment: The callback can be anything. And you don't need the cache buster if the code isn't running in a browser.

Comment: The callback doesn't evan have to be random. Just use `'callback', 'mycallback'`